# What is the best widget with GTK for chat window irc?

Tags: c, widget, gtk, irc

I'm programming a irc client in GTK, but i'm asking what is the best widget for the chat window ?
I think to use the GtkList but i'm not sure if it's the good widget for my problem.
Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textbox is necessary for user input.

Some people like to copy/paste from the room buffer. Whichever control you use for that, try to keep that in mind.

I suggest a treeview for the nicklist. Represent servers at the first level, channels and private messages at the second level and the nicklists for channels at the third level (when you expand channels).

Comment: @marcL You might even consider a HTML rendering engine for the room buffer. Consider passing colour, bold, underline and italics into HTML `<div class="colour-name">`, `<strong>`, `<em>`, etc... That way, if people want to remove or change a colour, it's as simple as changing the class-name for that colour. It'd be easier for the purpose of presenting logs, too, since they could be uploaded anywhere and viewed as HTML in all their correctly formatted glory...